# PHP encryption -> IONIC decryption = Truncate string

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework

I encrypt a URL in PHP 7 with:

```
$Url_Cript= base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, <secretKey 32 byte>, $Url, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB) );
```

and decrypt in Ionic with CryptoJS 3.1:

```
Url = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(Url_Cript,CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('<secretKey 32 byte>'),{mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Example of a URL that is truncated during decryption:

```
https://cdn-serv-video.domain-other.com/folder123/20210331_content123_123456.mp4

IjYmoYhtz8I9iXHWrYdk0u5+Q0wHfFGtAh6BdHdDsA8dA3hMrHy1Z1A24TBxfF07x1bYqiIRqWBNtDPZ46NZkMgtl0ksbQjSZHp8upuTMj0=

https://cdn-serv-video.domai
```

Example of a URL whose decryption works fine:

```
https://cdn-serv-video.domain-other.com/abcdefghi/20210331_content123456_abcdef.mp4

IjYmoYhtz8I9iXHWrYdk0u5+Q0wHfFGtAh6BdHdDsA9KnkY+4EekS\/qIqpFrZvIdD9od\/K9WAaolw5OXMbllTsuHYfVcys80BAFNiQMYnoLzuDToIEnLU0cGkxhf1ijZ

https://cdn-serv-video.domain-other.com/abcdefghi/20210331_content123456_abcdef.mp4
```

Sometimes the URL is truncated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Provide examples for minimal reproducible testing.

Comment: add example, it it important the key?

Comment: [Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) related issue. _mcrypt_ applies Zero padding, CryptoJS uses PKCS7 padding. Fix: Disable padding on the CryptoJS side ([`padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding)) and remove the `0x00` padding bytes at the end _manually_ (e.g. with [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)).

Comment: Btw, _mcrypt_ is deprecated and insecure. An alternative is [_openssl_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php), which also applies PKCS7 by default. ECB is also insecure, better use a mode with an IV.